# Android - TextView scrolling

Tags: android, textview

I would like to make a TextView scrolling automatically but I did not succeed
(as marquee in [html](http://www.csvt.qc.ca/patriotes/html/code_spec/xmpl_mrq.htm)). Could you tell me how?

Best Regard

Answer (score 5):

A TextView, with ellipsize set to "marquee", will not scroll unless it has the focus.

Are you looking for a marquee the scrolls regardless of the focus?

If so, you could use a TranslateAnimation with a LinearInterpolator to give it that consistent scrolling look. This is what I use and it works fine.

```
    DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    TranslateAnimation m_ta = new TranslateAnimation(dm.widthPixels, -1 * (dm.widthPixels), 0f, 0f);
    m_ta.setDuration(10000);
    m_ta.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    m_ta.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

    TextView m_tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvMarquee);
    m_tv.startAnimation(m_ta);
```

Comment: Freaking perfect! I knew the animation would be smoother than the default marquee textview (which is choppy and slow..). Thanks!

Comment: I have a TextView which has scrollbar and has text which extends past it's view so the scrollbar comes into view. How can I use your code so whenever the textview is displayed it will slowly scroll to the bottom but at the same time allows user interaction to scroll up and down?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at the `ellipsize` property of the TextView and set it to "marquee". Here's the 
[Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize).

Comment: With:
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"

The textview doesn't scroll :(